# Error in code ... need correction

Tags: bash, shell

I am extracting the values in fourth column of a file and trying to add them.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat tag_FLI1 | awk '{print $4}'>tags
$t=0 
for i in `cat tags`
    do
       $t=$t+$i  (this is the position of trouble) 
    done
echo $t
```

error on line 6.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of using only `awk` for the task:

If fields are separated with blanks:

```
awk '{ sum += $4 } END { print sum }' tag_FLI1
```

Otherwise, use `FS` variable, like:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "|" } { sum += $4 } END { print sum }' tag_FLI1
```

Comment: Power of `awk`. How easily 8-10 lines of code can be replace with a simple one liner. +1

Answer (score 3):

That's not how you do arithmetic in bash. To add the values from two variables `x` and `y` and store the result in a third variable `z`, it should look like this:

```
z=$((x + y))
```

However, you could more simply just do everything in awk, replacing your `awk '{print $4}'` with:

```
awk '{ sum += $4 } END { print sum }'
```

The awk approach will also correctly handle floating point numbers, which the bash approach will not.

Comment: +1 on the suggestion of handling of FP numbers. We can also use `z=$[x + y]` or use `let` or use `expr` for bash arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

That can be done in just one line:

```
awk '{sum += $4} END {print sum}' tag_FLI1
```

However, if this is a learning exercise for bash, have a look at this example:

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
while read line; do
    (( sum += $line ))
done < <(awk '{print $4}' tag_FLI1)
echo $sum
```

There were essentially 3 issues with your code:

1. Variables are assigned using `VAR=...`, not `$VAR=...`. See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html
2. The way you sum the numers is incorrect. See [arithmetic expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html) for examples of how to do it.
3. It is not necessary to use an intermediate file just to iterate through the output of a command. Use a while loop as show above, but beware of [this caveat](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: While your answer is correct and the code sample is good, I don't recommend linking new users to the ABS. It contains a lot of bad practices.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a numeric context for adding the numbers. Also, cat is not needed here, as awk can read from a file. Unless you use "tags" in another script, you don't need to create the file. Also, if you are using bash and not perl or php, there shouldn't be a "$" on the left side of a variable assignment.

```
t=0
while read -r i
do
   t=$((t + i))
done < <(awk '{print $4}' tag_FLI1)
echo "$t"
```